# read_csv with dates containing a dot as decimal separator and floats with a comma as decimal separator?

Tags: python, pandas

I have a csv file with a layout that looks like this:

```
date    a    b
2019-08-28 10:43:41.098  -1,9  -2,5
```

When I read this into pandas using

```
df = pd.read_csv(file,sep=None,parse_dates[0],engine='python',decimal=',')
```

and I look at the resulting dataframe, Pandas recognizes the `date` as `dtype: datetime64[ns]` but the other columns as `dtype: object`.

I have tried to skip the `decimal=','` part altogether but it doesn't help. I could try to individually replace the commas as dots but I wanted to see if there was a way to do it while importing the csv file directly.

Thanks in advance

EDIT: MWE

`data.txt`:

```
date    a   b   
08/28/2019 10:43:41.0980    -1,9    -2,5
```

```
import pandas as pd

df = pd.read_csv('C:/Users/USERNAME/Documents/Python/data.txt',sep=None,parse_dates=[0],engine='python').dropna(how='any',axis='columns')

print(df)
```

This code leads to `df` being equal to the aforementioned `data.txt`, but the data types are:

```
date    datetime64[ns]
a               object
b               object
dtype: object
```

Using `sep='\s{2,}'` as @furas suggested leads to the `df` being:

```
                             date\ta\tb
0  08/28/2019 10:43:41.0980\t-1,9\t-2,5
```

Comment: @elporche did you use " " as the delimiter at the moment?

Comment: create minimal working code which still have your problem so we could run it. When I create own working code then it convert it to float without problem. But your data doesn't works for me if I use `sep=None`. I had to use `sep='\s{2,}'`

Comment: @Tox I did not use "" as the delimiter. The reasoning behind `sep=None` is that the data will come from different computers; some use semicolons as separators and others use tabs. This way the script can remain flexible.

Comment: @furas added MWE. I could not get to read the data with `sep='\s{2,}'`

Comment: `sep='\s{2,}'` doesn't work because now I see your file uses tabs instead of spaces but data in question doesn't show it. I copied data with spaces and then it didn't works with `sep=None`

Comment: I created data with tabs and it correctly converts to float when I use `decimal=','`. In new code I see `dropna()` so problem can be NAN values in columns. It can't convert NAN to float so it doesn't convert other values in columns too. One of solution could be to drop NAN, save it in file and read it again with `decimal=','`

Comment: If I add value which is not float with dot or comma and system can't recognize it as NAN - ie. `'-'` - then it can't convert it to NAN and can't convert other values to float. But if I add this value to `read_csv(..., na_values=['-'])` then it automatically convert it to NAN and then it has no problem to convert float with `decimal=','`

Answer (score 0):

If the rest of the data set in column a and b does not match the same float format, pandas will infer dtype = object, i.e. `df = pd.DataFrame({'a': [1, 34, 34, 34, 'd', 2], 'b': [1, 34, 34, 34, 23, 2]})` 
yields

`0     1
1    34
2    34
3    34
4     d
5     2
Name: a, dtype: object
0     1
1    34
2    34
3    34
4    23
5     2
Name: b, dtype: int64`

If you want to discard rows that are not clean, you can run

`df = df.apply(pd.to_numeric, errors='coerce').dropna()
Out:
      a   b
0   1.0   1
1  34.0  34
2  34.0  34
3  34.0  34
5   2.0   2`

Comment: My issue is not the presence of different data formats in a single column, but rather the presence of different data formats across different columns i.e., one column will always have `datetime64[ns]` as format while the others will have `float64` (or at least that's what I want to do).

Answer (score 0):

What I ended up doing is:

```
df = pd.read_csv(file,sep=None,parse_dates[0],engine='python')

df = df.drop(columns=['date']).astype(str).apply(lambda x: x.str.replace(',','.')).astype(float).join(df['date'])
```

Cutting out the `'date'` column, converting to `str`, replacing commas for dots, and converting to `float` makes sure that the data can be read and the correct decimal separator be used regardless of the decimal separator in the dataset.

If the data has dots as decimal separators, the line of code will essentially do nothing while increasing the computational time (which is somewhat important to me when dealing with large datasets) but this approach seems to work without issues.

I still would like to find an approach that does this directly in the `read_csv` line.